# Ftp using filezilla in asp.net

Tags: asp-classic

i have created this file  in visual studio 2012 . The first page of survey works completely fine but when it re directs to display its showing '500 internal server error. The project has no compilation error . i am opening this file using filezilla can anyone please help me . its a simple program which fetches the value from survey.asp and displays the value in the next form in a tabular format.

------ survey.asp-----------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Survey Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="display.asp">
        <br/>
      Please Enter Your Age <input type="text" name="first" value="<%=request("Age")%>"/> <br /> <br/>
      Please Enter Your Salary $ <input type="text" name="sal" value="<%=request("salary")%>"/> <br /><br/>
      What level of Education Have You Completed : <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="<%=request("education")%>"/> Some High School <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="<%=request("education")%>"/> Completed high School <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="<%=request("education")%>"/>Some College Education  <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="<%=request("education")%>"/> Completed a B.S Degree <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="<%=request("education")%>"/> Completed a Master Degree <br /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Survey" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

----------display.asp---------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <%
    Age = request.form("first")
    salary = request.form("sal")
    education = request.form("radiobutton").ToString();
   if age="" or salary="" or education="" then
   %>
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
    <body>
You must enter all the info
<form method="post " action="survey.asp">
  <input type="hidden" name="age" value="<%=age%>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="salary" value="<%=salary%>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="education" value="<%=education%>" /> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Return" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

<%
response.end
end if
%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Display Name</title>
</head>
<body>

You entered: <br />
<table>
 <tr>
   <td> <%=age%> </td>
   <td> <%=salary%> </td>
   <td> <%=education %> </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is classic asp with vbscript, not asp.net with C#. You don't get compilation errors with classic because it isn't compiled, it's interpreted at runtime.

You appear to have put a line of C# in display.asp - if you replace the line

```
education = request.form("radiobutton").ToString();
```

with

```
education = Cstr(request.form("radiobutton"))
```

This should solve your initial 500 error.  Enclosing within `Cstr()` isn't actually necessary, but it's the VBScript way of converting to a string.

I don't think your radio button group will work as you have coded it.  If you're trying to preserve the original submitted value you should do something like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="1" <% If request.form("education") = "1" Then Response.write "checked" End if %> /> Some High School <br />
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="2" <% If request.form("education") = "2" Then Response.write "checked" End if %> /> Completed high School <br />
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="3" <% If request.form("education") = "3" Then Response.write "checked" End if %> />Some College Education  <br />
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="4" <% If request.form("education") = "4" Then Response.write "checked" End if %>/> Completed a B.S Degree <br />
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="5" <% If request.form("education") = "5" Then Response.write "checked" End if %>/> Completed a Master Degree <br /> <br/>
```

I'd suggest that having a second form on a different page isn't the best way to do form validation, better to have the form post to itself and use conditional statements to make error messages appear beside the individual form elements if nothing if they're left empty.

Finally, look at this page - it tells you how to enable useful error messages in Classic ASP.
http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp